# How would one be able to print only a specific set of lines in a JSON file using C++?

Tags: c++, json

This is the JSON file and I need to sort each "Sample", using sorting algorithms such as Mergesort, QuickSort, insertion sort etc. I can handle the sorting but how would I be able to access the values of the "Samples" because as soon as I iterate through the whole file, I also print the metadata which I don't want. How would I do so using C++?

```
{
  "Sample01": [
    1982297351,
    -1401779359,
    -1060884358,
    -526181663,
    512839761,
    1973273930,
    166828894,
    2118330955,
    -1205701654,
    1045410763
  ],
  "Sample02": [
    715111365,
    -1635156980,
    -1275799354,
    390902376,
    -1995120010,
    1079845325,
    -348388581,
    1487669981,
    946977879,
    -114777126
  ],
  "Sample03": [
    1887368688,
    -682665424,
    1115113643,
    -1244318203,
    -1165484372,
    913553810,
    1876752273,
    -1734982866,
    -197632295,
    -809020716
  ],
  "Sample04": [
    47979117,
    -1575893827,
    232070520,
    98942291,
    919917534,
    608798182,
    1098685159,
    2120663610,
    502723784,
    1754098591
  ],
  "Sample05": [
    -1941714245,
    -746761655,
    -194269038,
    -1274094575,
    -534237500,
    330995517,
    -1394100885,
    1843234851,
    -1636524188,
    1849312960
  ],
  "Sample06": [
    1563427224,
    866832458,
    1786768419,
    -1384300751,
    -2115741192,
    1794858015,
    2064677780,
    -569748690,
    201560529,
    1839266408
  ],
  "Sample07": [
    -1493722040,
    -1786039336,
    1929759925,
    16815988,
    -369302171,
    1246192730,
    -1757215234,
    736550370,
    96897197,
    -890156132
  ],
  "Sample08": [
    1380115946,
    2117857206,
    1496245749,
    -156983386,
    714565805,
    966168336,
    211590140,
    771013311,
    1341992631,
    -667519985
  ],
  "Sample09": [
    -1744375925,
    1839741715,
    1811248031,
    1763666372,
    1356783657,
    1175336051,
    260157377,
    956263021,
    915815615,
    1741220797
  ],
  "Sample10": [
    1999949854,
    1889430998,
    -439989550,
    -52691173,
    1466290457,
    845652536,
    1141819606,
    1123606984,
    554052149,
    1152333926
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "arraySize": 10,
    "numSamples": 10
  }
}
```

Comment: You either want to implement your own JSON parser (you probably don't), use regex to find and extract the `Sample`s or use an existing JSON library. What have you tried? Please include your attempt in your question.

Comment: Please show an [mcve] to show what you have done so far. Then we can give suggestions to make changes that will get you where you want to be.

Comment: Assuming that you are parsing the JSON and iterating over the keys, you can add an `if` statement to filter out the keys that you care about. Without some code, I cannot provide more details than this general idea.

Comment: There is no built-in JSON parser in C++. You will either have to write the code to manually parse it yourself or use some software library. Asking about software library recommendations is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: A generic JSON parser could be complex but parsing such files should be pretty simple. If there are no other fields you could try to parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward to read this file and parse it using std::ifstream::operator>>

```
Read char '{'
While true
    Read string name
    If name starts with "\"Sample"
        Read char '['
        While true
            Read number value
            Read char ',' or ']'
            If char is ']'
                Break
    Else
        Read char '{'
        While true
            Read string
            Read number
            Read char ',' or '}'
            If char is '}'
                Break
    Read char ',' or '}'
    If char is '}'
        Break
```

You store all items that start with "Sample

Comment: I don't think you can use that method in a JSON file

Comment: @RaunakAnand you can use this method on files with the format from your example. What files do you parse? The algorithm in my answer will parse the given file and extract the samples.